# How to test JPA2 mappings in Java EE project?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I'm working on a Java project where I've been tasked to write a few database mappings against a legacy database.
While doing this, I started to question how I was supposed to test if my mappings were valid or not. Most likely I've done a couple of mistakes in my mappings as I'm not a seasoned JPA annotations user.

So what is the general opinion/best-practice regarding testing manually written JPA mappings though annotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Hibernate, you can set the following in your `persistence.xml` file:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
```

to get Hibernate to validate the existing schema but *NOT* make any changes to the schema.  It's a quick way to see if your mappings are valid or not against your DB.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using OpenEJB to test entities mapping quite successfully in the EJB-based application. It has a nice transaction-rollback feature, thus, every unit test is independent (take a look at the "transaction-rollback" in the OpenEJB examples).

Generally, I think that the best practice is to test db mappings on the in-memory database (hsql for example) and to rollback changes at the end of every test case. You can also take a look at the [DBUnit project](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html).